# Remove all tags before and after a given id - Cheerio

Tags: html, web-crawler, cheerio

I am using cheerio to edit html, I get from crawling website.

I am trying to delete all tags before a given id and after a given id, for example, if my html is:

```
<div>
 <h2> This is it! </h2>
 <div>
   <h1> More helpful <h1>
 <div>
 <p> Hello, world </p>
 <h2 id='intro'> About the webpage <h2>
 <h2> This is it! </h2>
 <div>
   <h1> More helpful <h1>
 <div>
 <p> Hello, world </p>
 <p id="footer">footer</p>
 <h2> This is it! </h2>
 <div>
   <h1> More helpful <h1>
 <div>
 <p> Hello, world </p>
</div>
```

I want to remove all tags before id 'intro' and all tags after id 'footer', so that the resulting

```
<div>
 <h2 id='intro'> About the webpage <h2>
 <h2> This is it! </h2>
 <div>
   <h1> More helpful <h1>
 <div>
 <p> Hello, world </p>
 <p id="footer">footer</p>
</div>
```

how can I do it using cheerio or any other library? I am following https://cheerio.js.org/, I cannot find a way to select all peer tags before or after a given tag. Is it possible to do using some other library?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

```
cheerio('#intro', html).prevAll().remove();
cheerio('#footer', html).nextAll().remove();
```